# Container stretching with flex display

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following in my HTML file:

```
<div class="container-box">
    <div class="profile-box">
        <div class="image-container">
            <div class="profile-picture"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my CSS file, I have the following:

```
.container-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.profile-box {
  height: 350px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
```

This results in my profile-box being center-aligned, but I also want it vertically aligned. I have tried changing the flex-direction to row, but that only stretches it to take over all the horizontal space.

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/Humad/pen/rKLMeo

Comment: .container-box {
  height: 100vh;
}

.profile-box {
  /*flex: 1;*/
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546152/3597276

Comment: MickeyTheMouse, did my answer help you? If you need extra help, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already centered, but your `body` and `.container-box` do not have a height set for it go in the center.

## JSFiddle demo

```
body, html {
  height: 100%; /* added */
  width: 100%; /* added */
  margin: 0; /* added */
}

.container-box {
  height: 100%; /* added */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: black;
}
```